# regex not regexing correctly

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a simple parser for a language in python and I am using the re module that is built in with python.

for some reason the expression `[| ]*(\$ *[a-z0-9\-]+ *{ *[a-z0-9$\-{}"| ]* *})` does not match with the expression `$ math-mult {5|8}`.

I have reread the docs twice already and read most of the related stack overflow questions.

EDIT: here is the current parser:

```
def cut(line, remove_quotes = True):
pos = 0
tokens = []
regexprs = [
    (re.compile(r'[| ]*(\$ *[a-z0-9\-]+ *{ *[a-z0-9$\-{}"| ]* *})'), 'KEEP'),
    (re.compile(r'[| ]*"(.+?)"'), 'KEEP'),
    (re.compile(r'[a-z0-9]+'), 'KEEP'),
    (re.compile(' +'), 'THROW'),
    (re.compile('\|'), 'THROW')
]
if not remove_quotes:
    regexprs[0] = re.compile(r'[| ]*(".+?")')
while pos < len(line):
    for regex,status in regexprs:
        match = regex.match(line,pos)
        if match is not None:
            pos = match.end(0)
            if status == 'KEEP':
                tokens.append(match.group(regex.groups))
            break
    if match is None:
        end_pos = line.find(' ', pos)
        if end_pos == -1:
            end_pos = len(line)
        tokens.append(line[pos:end_pos])
        pos = end_pos + 1
return list(filter(lambda x: len(x.lstrip(' ')),tokens))
```

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: A [mcve] please.

Comment: @anubhava edited

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: selecting "Python" says ... it's missing a backslash before the quote! I am pretty sure that is not correct, it should not say that. But the OP must elaborate.

Comment: @usr2564301: that was my point: the "dialect" was wrong.

Comment: @anubhava passing pos to `.match` makes it start matching from that pos

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I'm on my iPad now so cannot readily test. But surely a regex delimited by single quotes do not require a double quote to be escaped? It would go against Python's rules of string definitions! The double quote itself is not a 'general' escaping character, and these should be resolved *before* handing over a string into a regex parser.

Comment: There is no `$ math-mult {5|8}` in your code. How can it fail then?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: doesn't matter: https://regex101.com/r/1oBmMb/2

Comment: `for some reason the expression [| ]*(\$ *[a-z0-9\-]+ *{ *[a-z0-9$\-{}"| ]* *}) does not match with the expression $ math-mult {5|8}` Well, this is not true. So, you must want people to debug your _other code_. I'm voting to close.

Comment: `.match` will only work with input: `'$ math-mult {5|8}'`  when `pos=0` but for any other `pos` value it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

The regexp that should match is the first element of the regexprs array (i.e. `regexprs[0]`). This code:

```
if not remove_quotes:
   regexprs[0] = re.compile(r'[| ]*(".+?")')
```

is replacing that regexp with a new one.